# Optimizing query to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to optimize the following SQL query? I have this query which works but I need to optimize it, or do you have a suggestion for an online SQL refactoring tool?

Table: `Membership`

```
+---------+--------+
| GroupID | UserID |
+---------+--------+
|     123 |    605 |
|     124 |    605 |
|     125 |    605 |
|     123 |    606 |
|     125 |    606 |
|     124 |    607 |
+---------+--------+
```

Table: `content_group_membership`

```
+---------+-----------+
| GroupID | ContentId |
+---------+-----------+
|   11111 |       123 |
|   22222 |       123 |
|   44444 |       124 |
|   22222 |       125 |
|   11111 |       126 |
|   33333 |       126 |
|   11111 |       125 |
+---------+-----------+
```

The `Membership` table holds the list of `groupID` the user belongs to and the `content_group_membership` table hold the list of permitted `ContentID` for the corresponding `groupID`.

We need to get the list of `contentID` which are restricted for that user, `groupID` for the `UserID` should be taken from `Membership` table and the `contentID` with `groupID` of other than user's `groupID` are restricted `ContentID` for that `UserID`.

Below is the query, right now we are using which is consuming triple the amount of time consumed to fetch the result when the below query is used as sub query. So, we want an optimized query to fetch results quickly.

Expected result : 33333

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   [ContentID], groupid
FROM   
   [content_group_membership]
WHERE  
   contentid NOT IN (SELECT [ContentID]
                     FROM [content_group_membership]
                     WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT groupid
                                       FROM Membership
                                       WHERE UserID = 605 ))
   AND GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID
                   FROM [content_group_membership]
                   WHERE groupid NOT IN (SELECT groupid
                                         FROM Membership
                                         WHERE UserID = 605))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you want.  Sample data and desired results are useful.  A query that matches the data structure is important.  For instance, what is `Active = 1`?

Comment: What is slow about it? Have you ran a (SSMS) SQL Server Management Studio Execution Plan?

To do the latter, open SSMS, paste in your code to a query window, and hit Ctrl+L. Then, view the results and post.

What tool are you using to build and execute the SQL if not SSMS?

Comment: @Linoff , Active = 1 is the user should be an active user. I have removed it as i have not using in the sample table. I have also updated my question. Let me know if you need more info. I think multiple  sub query slows down the performance also the subquery to get user group id is duplicated. So..need it in a best way of quering...

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent, and run more efficiently:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT [ContentID],
                groupid
FROM   [content_group_membership]
WHERE  contentid != ANY (SELECT [ContentID]
                         FROM   [content_group_membership]
                         WHERE  GroupID IN (SELECT groupid
                                            FROM   Membership
                                            WHERE  UserID = 605
                                                   AND Active = 1))
   AND GroupID NOT IN (SELECT groupid
                       FROM   Membership
                       WHERE  UserID = 605
                       AND Active = 1))
```

However, a query of this complexity might be better off as a procedure.